# Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS no internet using static IP for ethernet and dynamic for WIFI

Tags: networking, server, iptables, dhcp, raspberrypi

I'm configuring a raspberry cluster using Ubuntu Server 64bits 20.04.

I need a static ip for my master and the master will also share the internet from the wifi forwarding to the ethernet and then to all nodes. Already applied the iptables rules that worked for me before in other setups without netplan, but doesn't work.

What is not working is the internet, when I have the ethernet cable connected to the switch, the internet is unreachable from the master node and the other nodes. The DHCP seems correct, all nodes are getting the ip. The frustration is that with the old interfaces configuration everything worked fine, but with this netplan file I can't make it work.

## How it's configured:

### netplan for master node

```
version: 2
ethernets:
  eth0:
    dhcp4: no
    addresses:
      - 10.0.0.1/24
    gateway4: 10.0.0.1
    nameservers:
      addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
wifis:
  wlan0:
    dhcp4: true
    optional: true
    access-points:
      "mywifi":
        password: "pwd"
```

### DHCP

I installed `isc-dhcp-server` everything looks fine

#### /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.config

```
option domain-name "fals.cloud";
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

ddns-update-style none;

authoritative;

subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.10;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 10.0.0.1;
  option broadcast-address 10.0.0.255;
}
```

#### cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

```
1
```

#### cat /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server

```
INTERFACESv4=eth0
INTERFACESv6=eth0
```

#### dhcp-lease-list

```
MAC                IP              hostname       valid until         manufacturer
===============================================================================================
dc:a6:32:3f:7b:03  10.0.0.4        ubuntu         2020-11-01 17:15:07 -NA-
dc:a6:32:3f:7b:c3  10.0.0.2        ubuntu         2020-11-01 17:14:47 -NA-
dc:a6:32:3f:7e:18  10.0.0.3        ubuntu         2020-11-01 17:14:55 -NA-
```

#### iptables -L -v -n | more

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 790 packets, 54205 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 6594 packets, 410K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  wlan0  eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   wlan0   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 3728 packets, 341K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

#### ip route

```
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 proto static
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.53 metric 600
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.53
192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.53 metric 600
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delete the default route via 10.0.0.1 
Your "master" is basically a router and it has to know one and only one default route.
In the netplan, delete `gateway4: 10.0.0.1`
Then run:

```
sudo netplan generate --debug
```

If there are no errors:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

Remember that your internet gateway (192.168.0.1) will need NAT for your 10.0.0.0/24 network or you will need to add the NAT from 10.0.0.0/24 to IP learned from DHCP server if you want your nodes to reach the internet.

Comment: Hey what you suggested worked. Just checked a node in the network everything seems ok, i can connect to the internet. I configured the share with a iptable forward as I mentioned in the question. Best regards!

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. Just FYI, the rules in FORWARD chain, don't do anything because the default policy is already ACCEPT. If your nodes can reach internet it means, the gateway router (192.168.0.1) has masquerade enabled and it is NATing all networks.

Comment: I have a MASQUERED rule applied :)