# Ubuntu Server 22.04: Internet is not working after configuring Static IP

Tags: networking, server, internet, dhcp, static-ip

I was changing my network configuration from dhcp to assigning a Static IP, but after changing, the internet just won't work with my set Static IP. However reverting back to its dhcp conf. makes everything work normally.

First, I used to get a warning that `the 'gateway4' address has been deprecated`. I applied some changes and the warnings didn't come back after that, but the internet was not working at all.

I tried many solution in Stack Exchange, but they didn't work.

These are the configurations with dhcp:

[image]

I have changed the configuration for static IP:

[image]

Previously I was using 'gateway4', but omitted it after one of the solutions advised to apply later as code `sudo netplan generate --debug`, but nothing changed.

[image]

When I changed my network to static, internet just won't work.

Previously I used sources from these to resolve this issue:

- [Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS no internet using static IP for ethernet and dynamic for WIFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288833/ubuntu-server-20-04-lts-no-internet-using-static-ip-for-ethernet-and-dynamic-for)
- [No internet connection after setting static ip in Ubuntu](https://forums.fogproject.org/topic/4229/solved-no-internet-connection-after-setting-static-ip-in-ubuntu)
- [Ubuntu 14.04: Setting static IP](https://wiki.fogproject.org/wiki/index.php/Ubuntu_14.04#Setting_static_IP)
- [Canonical netplan examples](https://netplan.io/examples/)

Comment: Simply changing the IP on the machine won't fix the network that is being connected to.  The connected network is relying on IPs between 10.0.2.0 and 10.0.2.255.  You will need to set an IP address that is within that range staticly on the network.  DHCP being enabled aside, you still have to match the subnet that the network accepts in order to get network connectivity.

Comment: @ThomasWard , so does it mean i cant give a static IP to my server without having routes via range of 10.0.2.0 - 10.0.2.255. ?? How do i do that?

Comment: use any IP within that range other than .1 .2 or .255 in your IP address on your netplan config.  use /24 for the cidr.  define a route for default traffic communication on your network (see https://netplan.io/examples/#using-dhcp-and-static-addressing for examples)

Comment: ok, i will. I am trying to understand. So, I cant use static IPs from my routers directly?(Like 192.168.0.50/24). Can u explain a bit @ThomasWard , bcuz, i hv read and seen in videos people assigning Static IPs that of present in router. Is it not possible for my server? By the way, i am using ubuntu in VirtualBox.

Comment: how is the network in the Vbox VM set up?  Bridged or NAT?  If it's Bridged you have to use the IP from the router.  If it's NAT, then you have to refer to the advanced VBox network device administration for how to enable/disable DHCP and to find the ip range that the VBox NAT device uses.  (VBox networking is confusing - see https://www.nakivo.com/blog/virtualbox-network-setting-guide/ for what I mean heh)

Comment: The whole IP address changing is truly the most annoying thing in the world. I've now wasted about a day of my life changing the IP and/or trying to get it to not change. Needs to be redone.

Answer (score 2):

I also spent some time trying to find out how to set a static IP address on Ubuntu 22.04. (Ubuntu Server 22.04.02 LTS)

That is the solution that worked for me:

1. Open cloud-init file '/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/subiquity-disable-cloudinit-networking.cfg' and make sure that entry "network: {config: disabled}" is here.
2. Open the file /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml. Roughly you are going to see something like this:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

The content of this file depends on your network settings.

**Note:** In my netplan directory I had a single file **/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml**. If you have other configuration files you may need to review them as well.

3. From the above you can see that the IP address is set automatically by DHCP server. You need to modify the file /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml so that static IP is set as static.

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
# Modified on 2023.05.01
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.56.5/24]
      nameservers: 
        addresses: [8.8.8.4,8.8.8.8]
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.56.1
  version: 2
```

a) you set **dhcp4** to false to disable automatic IP setup

b) in **adresses** part you need to set the IP address, in my case this is 192.168.56.5 and my subnet masks is 24.

c) **nameservers:** I'm using Google Public DNS

d) **routes: via:** you need to set the gateway IP address, in my case this is 192.168.56.1

This is it.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas Ward gave you the solution in his first comment.
Since everything was working when DHCP was used you have to use an Ip between 10.0.0.3 and 10.0.0.254. Even 10.0.0.1 might work if it isn't used by any other device. Use 10.0.0.2 as your gateway since that is your router.
You cannot use 192.168.56.0/24 as your network just because someone used in a tutorial